# issue with string copying

Tags: c, string

I have assignment where I need to copy a string 'src' to a string 'dst' but I need to do this without "string.h" and the strings aren't ending to '\0' instead they are ending to '?' . So this function "es_cat" needs to return the number of characters of the return string and in this case its 26 and that's correct for me. But the problem is that the string "dst" should be the return string after the function is complete and in the function I even put "c = dst" and then print it and it shows me that that's the correct return string but still from the assignment checker I'll get this error :

test_source.c:129:F:test_es_cat:test_es_cat:0: [07_altstring.c] Copied string is incorrect with inputs "Foobar123neljaa?viisibaz" and "56seitseman?kasiysikymppi". Should have been "Foobar123neljaa56seitseman?", you have "Foobar123neljaa?viisibaz"

```
int es_cat(char *dst, char *src) {
   char c[100] = {dst[0]};
   int i = 0;
   while (*dst != '?') {
       c[i] = *dst;
       dst++;
       i++;
   }
   while (*src != '?') {
       c[i] = *src;
       src++;
       i++;
   }
   c[i] = '?';
   dst = c;
   printf("\n%s", dst);
   return i;
}
int main(void) {
   char lol[256] = "Foobar123neljaa?viisibaz";
   char asd[256] = "56seitseman?kasiysikymppi";
   int res = es_cat(lol, asd);
   printf("\n%d", res);
}
```

Comment: Even if the assignment to `dst = c;` was visible outside of function `es_cat`, the memory holding `c` wouldn't be valid any more after leaving that function. Also strings must be terminated with a 0 byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in C arguments are passed *by value*. That means they are *copied* and the function can modify its own copy as much as it wants without anything happening to the original. When you do `dst = c` you modify the *local copy* of `dst` not what the `lol` variable points to inside the `main` function.

Besides that, what you attempt to do is to make `dst` point to the *local variable* `c` (or rather the first element of `c`). This is problematic since once the function returns `c` will go out of scope and cease to exist.

To solve this, I recommend you create the array `c` in the *`main`* function, and pass a pointer to its first character as an argument to the function.

If you're supposed to actually copy the string to `dst`, then first of all you can't have `lol` being a pointer to a string literals, because literal strings are *read only arrays* of characters. As *read only* you can not modify them, and as *arrays* they have a fixed size that can not be modified. To solve this you could do e.g.

```
char lol[256] = "Foobar123neljaa?viisibaz";
```

That makes `lol` an array whose contents can be modified. And hopefully big enough to contain the full concatenated string. And instead of just copying pointers (what happens with `dst = c`) you should write directly to `dst` (or at least [copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to it).

---

As you seem to need hand-holding and can't seem to think for yourself (harsh but that's what it seems like) here's a functioning program which modifies `dst` in place:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int es_cat(char *dst, const char *src)
{
    // Save so we can calculate the length later
    const char *orig_dst = dst;

    // First find the insertion point in the destination string
    while (*dst != '\0' && *dst != '?')
    {
        ++dst;
    }

    // Now dst is either pointing to the terminator, or the '?'
    // Copy from src into dst, until the "end" of src
    while (*src != '\0' && *src != '?')
    {
        *dst++ = *src++;
    }

    // Terminate the destination
    *dst = '\0';

    // Calculate the length of the string in dst, and return it
    return dst - orig_dst;
}

int main()
{
    char lol[256] = "Foobar123neljaa?viisibaz";
    const char *asd = "56seitseman?kasiysikymppi";

    int ret = es_cat(lol, asd);
    printf("result = '%s', length = %d\n", lol, ret);

    return 0;
}
```

[See here for it running](https://ideone.com/XnTbe6).

Comment: I have to use the function "int es_cat(char *dst, char *src)" exactly like this so the input has to be a pointer

Comment: @michael Remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element! For example if you have `char lol[256]`, passing `lol` as an argument is the same as doing `&lol[0]`.

Comment: I edited it to that but no change, How could I write the function directly to dst and not using that c at all?

Comment: yea this works thank you but in this way in the result there is 'Foobar123neljaa56seitseman' and it should be 'Foobar123neljaa56seitseman?' with the question mark in the end of it

Comment: @michael After the second loop, add a check if `*src` is a question-mark, and just copy it the same as in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

you have few problems here.first of all take destination string big enough so that it can copy source string if source is bigger,another thing is you need to do strcpy(or memcpy,strcpy is preferred) in es_cat as directly assigning pointer of local array c won't copy whole string in destination,your code might look something like this :

```
#define STRING_SIZE  1000
int es_cat(char *dst, char *src) {
   char c[STRING_SIZE*2];
   int i = 0;
   while (*dst != '?') {
       c[i] = *dst;
       dst++;
       i++;
   }
   while (*src != '?') {
       c[i] = *src;
       src++;
       i++;
   }
   c[i] = '?';
   memcpy(dst,c,i);
   dst[i+1] = '\0';//add null
   printf("\n%s", dst);
   return i;
}
int main(void) {
   char dest[STRING_SIZE*2] = "Foobar123neljaa?viisibaz";
   char source[STRING_SIZE] = "56seitseman?kasiysikymppi";
   int res = es_cat(lol, asd);
   printf("\n%d", res);
}
```

Comment: Need to do this without string.h and strcpy() is included in that right?

Comment: memcpy() is same kind of library function and I cant use string.h

Comment: take a while loop and copy content of c into dst until you get null or '?' .somethat similar to what you did to copy source and dst to local buffer c.